# GitLab not sending notifications to merge request approvers

Tags: gitlab

I have written an entire software development course, and until recently we've been using Bitbucket. I recently rewrote the course to use GitLab instead, mostly because GitLab the username isn't tied to a particular email like Bitbucket. I had heard good things. But I'm running into problems already.

The first is that merge requests (what the other hosting services call "pull requests") are not sending out notifications to approvers. We just had the lesson where I taught my students to create merge requests. I had them add me as "Reporter" to their projects. Then I had them create a merge request, and add me as an "Approver".

Yet I received no email notifying me that two student had created merge requests with me as an approver on each. I double-checked, and my global notifications are set to "Participate".

I reported this issue in a [comment to a GitLab ticket](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/42#note_129590841), but received no response. I even filed a [new official GitLab bug report](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/56659); someone finally looked at it, and created [another ticket for GitLab EE](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/9355). So far no one has actually found the problem.

So as a workaround I went into my GitLab nofication settings and set the notification level for each student repository to "Watch" so that I (in theory) should be notified of any activity at all. Sure enough, I was notified when my students created merge requests.

Unfortunately even with a notification level of "watch", I was not notified when a student updated a merge request by making a new commitment to the branch and pushing it to GitLab.

Am I doing something wrong? Why am I not getting notifications of merge requests on which I am approver—not even when I'm watching the project? If I can't get this simple, core functionality to work I guess we'll move to Github, now that they introduced private repositories.

*Update:* I finally abandoned GitLab, primarily because of basic issues like this one. I rewrote the software development course again, this time using GitHub.

Comment: Have you ever received emails? Can you put the logs? Can you put your email configuration in the server? The correct option is "Participate" as you already have.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, after setting the repository to "Watch", I received notification of new merge requests (which I should have received already, as an approver), but I do not receive notifications of commits added to the merge request. I do receive emails when comments are made to the merge request.

Answer (score 2):

Role "Reporter" cannot accept/manager Merge Requests in the repository. See the [whole list of permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) but basically they are:

> Guest: Read only access
>
> Reporter: Issues and comments
>
> Developer: Push, actions to the repository
>
> Maintainer: Admin

I did not test myself but maybe [GitLab notifications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/notifications.html) check this internally. My recommendation is to [protect the master branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) or develop depending on your Git Workflow. Ideally **only Maintainers** can push or merge to protected branches after code review, so you should be assigned this role in the repos to approved things and hopefully receive the notifications. The global notification should be **"Participate"** and this is propagated to all your repos to avoid be overwhelmed by notifications ("Watch" notify all the activities in the repos). Developers should create feature or bugfix branches from master/develop and push always to this branch.

**Suggestion**

I would research some Git Workflow: [Github](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/10/25/gitlab-workflow-an-overview/) or [GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) are very good examples to analyse. You can adapt the workflow to your own needs. Another MUST should be to configure [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/) before merging into the protected branches to assure the robustness and quality of the code and teach the students good practices from the beginning.

**UPDATE 2**

This is happening in the CE and EE. No emails are sent when pushing new commits to Merge Requests. I tested with "Watch", "Custom", "Participate", "Developer", "Maintainer" and no emails have been sent. Actually "Custom" has an specific option for "Push to Merge Requests". However even not ideal, there is a workaround if you want to use it. Actually it also sends the diff between commits inside the email. In Settings/Integration there is an option `Emails on push`. You can configure there a list of emails to send the notifications. See the image below. If you want to be informed when someone push new commits to the MR another workaround is to configure the CI pipeline. You will receive an email if the pipeline fails or succeeds (this is the way we are doing). Let's wait until GitLab people answers to your GitLab ticket. If this is a **NO GO** issue for you and none of the workarounds work for you, I would move to **GitHub Private Repositories**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "accept Merge Requests"? By "accept", do you mean "mark the merge request as approved", or do you mean "perform the merge, completing the merge request"?

Comment: I meant perform the MR, but if you check the permissions (see the link above), reporters cannot``Manage/Accept merge requests``. I am not used to the Enterprise Edition becaus in the open source version this functionality is not available. It is quite weird that you are not receiving the MR emails. One case For instance no emails are sent is when you open the MR and you assign to yourself.

Comment: "I meant perform the MR…." But I don't want to perform the merge request. I only want to be allowed to _approve_ it. I am set as "Reporter" on the project, which is appropriate for being added as an approver. You have a lot of things in the answer (talking about merging the request, and suggestions for changing my course I've written) completely ancillary to the reported problem. The problem is that GitLab is not sending merge request creation and update notifications to an approver. This answer does not address that, but gave unrelated suggestions such as protecting the master branch.

Comment: I answered your question at the beginning. Reporters cannot manage MR. Change to another role and "Participate". "Watch" is a terrible option. Merge Requests are useless without protected branches and CI pipeline. I addressed efforts to improve your approach and I am ok you do not want to update your course. Enterprise Edition has its own supporting system so contact directly to them.

Comment: "Reporters cannot manage MR." I do not want to manage the merge request. I want to approve the merge request. GitLab is letting me approve the merge request—that is not the problem! The problem is a lack of notifications; that is the crux of this question. Notifications—not managing, not merging, not protecting branches. If I am assigned as an approver of a merge request, I should get an email notifying me of that. The question really is that simple: "Why am I not getting an email notification for something I've been assigned to as an approver?"

Comment: I already mentioned that even with my notification set to "watch", which according to the documentation (which you linked to) should send me a "notification for any activity", I don't get a notification for new commits to a merge request.

Comment: This is becoming personal, I found a workaround even it is not the ideal solution

Comment: Hey, Carlos. Being a bit nit-picky I'd have to admit that some of your feedback was a little off-topic, discussing managing/accepting the merge request and protecting the branches. But you sure have put a lot of work into this, you've found a partial workaround, and you're contributing extra test information to the GitLab bug, all of which I appreciate. I'll assign the bounty to you for your hard work. Thanks for your efforts and help!

Comment: Really appreciated! I did not read in depth the central point of your question at the beginning, so you were right and I was not able to test the issue because we use the CE. Hope they solve the bug!

Comment: @GarretWilson I will update the GitLab issue but for you to know. In our git workflow we merge features to develop branch. Today I received an email when someone push to a Merge Request to master (from develop). So the issue in CE only happens if the target branch on MR is not master (I do not know if it is your case)

Answer (score 0):

[`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 9355](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/9355#note_162584962) mentioned at the time (4 years ago, 2019)

> I managed to work around it by setting the Notification level of the approver group to `Watch` - and they now receive the emails when the MR Approval is requested.
> In our case, the affected groups are used for nothing but MR Approvals, so this workaround is fine for us.
> In your case, it would no doubt result in some noise to be notified about every interaction. I suppose you could filter them out - but it's still not ideal.

[GitLab 16.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/12/21/gitlab-16-7-released/#notify-me-when-any-merge-request-needs-approval) (December 2023) proposes an alternative approach, which could mitigate the issue:

> ### Notify me when any merge request needs approval
>
> When your approval is required for a merge request, you need to be notified to take action.
>
> Some users only want notifications when their approval is required, which is typically done by adding a user by name to review the changes.
>
> However, some users want a notification for any merge request they are eligible to approve, *even if they aren’t added by name as reviewers*.
>
> Enable the **Added as approver** custom notification level to trigger an email and to-do for each merge request you are eligible to approve.
> This helps you be aware of merge requests sooner in the process, and take action to get the proposal merged.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_7/create-optional-approval-notification.png -- Notify me when any merge request needs approval]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html#edit-notification-settings) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/12855).